# Automating the copy paste process in excel along with offsetting

Tags: vba

I want to copy the values of range N17:N18 and paste transpose them into another cell. However after doing the same, I want to offset one row and paste the value of the given range into the new active cell. I am using a data solver function, so I want to paste each new value of N17:N18 for each new constraint.

Following are the steps that i want to cover:

1. copy range N17:N18, paste into N21-offset 1 row
2. run solver function to get new values
3. paste into N22 (N21-offset 1 row)
4. run solver function to get new values
5. paste into N23 (N22-offset 1 row)

this goes on for all the new values.....

Comment: Please show sample dta, desired output and share with us what have you tried already.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to do this manually, select the required range of values in the excel sheet and press Ctrl+C to copy

Then select the Location where you want to paste, right click, paste special and then click the transpose check box.

[Screenshot with steps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TPfka.png)

If you're looking for a programmatic solution, then I suggest Excel Macros (please modify it to the cells you desire). Hope this helps.

```
Sub transpose_selection()
    Range("A1:C4").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("E1").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
        False, Transpose:=True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I am new to VBA Coding, so thank you for addressing my doubt.

After fiddling with the code I was able to find a solution. Here it is, hope this helps someone.

```
Sub SolverShortcut()
'
' SolverShortcut_PasteSpecial-ValuesandTranspose Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+l
'
    SolverOk SetCell:="$N$17", MaxMinVal:=1, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$P$2:$P$6", _
        Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
    SolverAdd CellRef:="$N$17", Relation:=2, FormulaText:="$P$16"
    SolverOk SetCell:="$N$17", MaxMinVal:=1, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$P$2:$P$6", _
        Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
    SolverOk SetCell:="$N$17", MaxMinVal:=1, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$P$2:$P$6", _
        Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
    SolverSolve
    '
' PasteSpecial_valuesandtranspose Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+l
'
    Range("N17:N18").Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=True
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
End Sub
```

ANY FORM OF CONSTRUCTIVE CRITICISM IS ALWAYS WELCOME.